# Highlighted number of unread messages; could it update and remain highlighted?

Tags: feature-request

When I arrive at *ELU*, if I have unread messages or notifications, I see a highlighted number next to the "StackExchange" element of the page headline. When I open the drop-down box and use it as a link to one of these items, the highlighted number vanishes, even if I started with multiple messages unread.

Can we have this number remain, and remain highlighted, with the number of as-yet unread messages or notifications? I would like to be able to know by this indicator if I've read them all or not.

Comment: The downside of this proposal is that the number would remain there until I visited each of the messages from the alert link - even if I've already seen them.

Comment: I don't care if the number stays there or not, but it would be helpful to keep the _Inbox_ menu on top until one has gone through the messages; I often look at one and get involved, forgetting that there are more, and they don't pop up when I look because what's always on top is _Hot Questions_, which is not really relevant here.

Comment: Actually, J.R., part of my suggestion is that the number should update itself (magically!!) so that it reflects only the number of unread messages. I didn't state that clearly enough, but that was my intention when I said "as-yet unread."

Comment: This should maybe be on SO Meta, since it is a feature-request that would affect SE globally, presumably.

Comment: @KitFox I seem to recall that this was a denied feature request on MSO.

Comment: I use a right-click to open each new message in a new window. That seems to keep the number there & the new messages highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Agree wholeheartedly. In its present format and layout, the highlighted *news* is counter-intuitive. Click on one, the others should remain "unread" not fade back with the others.

P.S an option to **enlarge** the "Stack Exchange" box, would be handy. The print is quite quite tiny and I can't always find my reading glasses. :)

Comment: Resizing text is a feature of most browsers. In several I use, the controls are Control +, Control -, and Control 0.

Comment: @MετάEd Thank you, I keep forgetting these keyboard tricks exist! But I was thinking of more on the lines of dragging the corners, as in the comment box, it would aid legibility IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I'll reproduce J.R.'s comment here, because I think it's an important factor...

> The downside of this proposal is that the number would remain there until I visited each of the messages from the alert link - even if I've already seen them.

I must admit when I started on ELU I used to get irritated by the "alert list" being cleared completely every time I followed a single link in it.

But then I wised up and started checking out comments *starting with the oldest one*. Provided I look at all outstanding items within one continuous process, I only have to remember *the one I was just looking at* when I return to the inbox (and move on to *the one above that*).

Unless I make a real effort, I'm positively *meshless* [sieve-brained](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sieve-like), but this much I can manage.

Comment: I just middle-click the one that I want to see, so that the list doesn’t go away.

Comment: @tchrist: I was only saying to a Mac-owning mate yesterday that having two mouse buttons was well worth it, but so far as I knew the third/middle button never really turned out to be much use, so they stopped bothering with it. I love browsing with my trusty Logitech mouse and its *back/forward* side buttons, but it's never even occurred to me to see if *pressing* the top wheel would do anything useful (if it works for this, it'll be a toss-up between whether I'll be wanting to marry *you*, or Logitech's Head of Design! :)

Comment: Yes, it’s a Logitech mouse I’m using. Press the middle wheel: it’s a middle button.  The middle button is normally used for pasting, but on a link, it opens the link in a separate tab. At least, the way I have things configured.